# Trouble Assigning User Attributes Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, attributes, devise

I have a rails app with devise for my user model. In my app users can enroll in courses through enrollments. I added hour_learned and hours_taught. After enrollment I try to add hours learned to the current user but for some reason it just won't work. I don't get any error but it just won't insert into the db. I have an enroll method in my user model that looks like this:

```
def enroll!(course, user)
    enrollments.create!(:course_id => course.id, :active => true)
    user.hours_taught = user.hours_taught + (course.hours_long)
end
```

And yes I made sure the the attributes are accessible. Still no go. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you need `user.save` after updating the hours_taught attribute.

Comment: But the user already exists in the db and it's not an instance variable. Should I still user .save?

Comment: Never mind you were totally right, nice call. Can't believe I forgot that.

Comment: All of the model's attributes are instance variables--they don't get saved/updated to the db until you explicitly call the save method. This is a feature to minimize database operations.

Comment: Glad to help and welcome to stack overflow. Remember to upvote answers that you find useful, including answers to others' questions. Also remember to "accept" (check) the one answer to your questions which best answers your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why is this method that you're defining on the `User` model taking a `user` object as a parameter? You should define it like this:

```
def enroll!(course)
  enrollments.create!(:course => course, :active => true)
  self.hours_taught = self.hours_taught + (course.hours_long)
  self.save!
end
```

This method will be defined as an instance method on this class so you can call it like this:

```
user.enroll!(course)
```

This means that you won't need to pass through user as an argument this method. Inside the method, we take the `course` object and assign it to the enrolment, do the hours math and then save it using `save!`, which will raise an exception if the reocrd is invalid (either an `ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid` or `ActiveRecord::RecordNotSaved`)

Answer (score 0):

What error msg do you get?

Also, usually a model's instance method would not include a parameter for the obj itself. Use `self` within the model. Eg

```
class User << ActiveRecord::Base
  ...

  def enroll!(course)
    enrollments.create!(:course_id => course.id, :active => true)
    self.hours_taught = self.hours_taught + (course.hours_long)
    save!
  end
  ...
```

**Added** Why save is needed...

Remember that ActiveRecord really keeps track of its models' data in two places: in "memory" and in the database system.

Since saving/updating a record's database copy is expensive in terms of time, you may want to do a number of updates to the in-memory version of the record and then save it to the database.

Or, again depending on the situation, you may want a given operation against the model to be atomic and include saving the updated model to the database.

In this example, you've named the method enroll! The ! is a convention which implies that you want the enroll! method to "do it all," including updating the database.

In the method itself, therefore, you need to save the data to the dbms.

The problem with including `save` in an object's method is that you may end up with more saves to the database then are really needed. It is much better to save multiple changes all at once than to make multiple saves to the db. But you don't want to twist yourself into knots to minimize saves. -- Just keep the issue in mind while planning your sw flow.